# Mocking file system contents not working with gulp.src

Tags: node.js, mocking, gulp

I'm trying to use [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs) to mock up file system contents to test gulp tasks.  Unfortunately, `gulp.src` doesn't seem to play well with `mock-fs`.  Specifically, I get ENOENT errors:

```
Message:
    ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/study-node-heroku/instances/development/app.json'
Details:
    errno: -2
    code: ENOENT
    path: /vagrant/study-node-heroku/instances/development/app.json
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
Stack:
Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/study-node-heroku/instances/development/app.json'
    at Error (native)
```

Other parts of my code and test code access the `mock-fs`-created files just fine.

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect that the problem is related to gulp's usage of vinyl.

Here is the function under test:

```
var herokuTarball = function(options, done) {
  var instance = options.instance || 'development';
  var tarballName = options.tarballName || instance
  var tarballPath = path.join(config.temp, tarballName + '.tar.gz');
  var files = path.join(config.instances, instance, '**/*');
  yassert.file(path.join(config.instances, instance, 'app.json'));

  async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
      del([tarballPath], cb);
    },
    function(err, cb) {
      gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(tar(tarballName + '.tar'))
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp))
        .pipe(gcallback(cb));
    }
  ], function(err, result) {
    if (err) return err;
    return done(err, tarballPath);
  });
}
```

And here is the test snippet:

```
describe('gulp heroku:tarball', function() {
  after('something', function() {
    mock.restore();    
  });

  before('something', function() {
    mock({
      'instances/development': {
        'app.json': 'test content'
      }
    });
  });

  it('creates a tarball', function(done) {
    var options = {}

    heroku.herokuTarball(options, function(err, result) {
      expect(result).to.be.a('string');
      yassert.file(result);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Notice that the yassert (yeoman-assert) calls pass fine -- the file is there.  If I take the function with the gulp.src call out of the async waterfall, the error goes away (and the test fails of course).

Issue posted at https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, [mock-fs README](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/blob/master/readme.md#using-with-other-modules-that-modify-fs) states:

> **Note** mock-fs is not compatible with graceful-fs@3.x but works with graceful-fs@4.x.

Looking at the dependencies of [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) we get:

```
$ npm info gulp devDependencies.graceful-fs
^3.0.0
```

Hence, gulp is still dependent on graceful-fs@3.x, therefore mock-fs will not work.

YMMV, but maybe [vinyl-fs-mock](https://github.com/timnew/vinyl-fs-mock) is an alternative?